# Solving ODE with assumption that solution is bounded at boundaries?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

For a HW problem, this ODE had boundary conditions given that are not the normal boundary conditions, instead the problem says that solution $u(t)$ is bounded at the left and right ends of the domain.

So I could not verify my solution using Mathematica, because I do not know how to tell `DSolve` this boundary condition. But I think my solution is correct.

So I am asking if there is a trick or a way to specify this boundary condition in Mathematica. Below the ODE is given, and my hand solution and the Mathematica code, but without the BC specified (since do not know how)

### ODE to solve

Solve the inhomogeneous Legendre differential equation
$$
\left(  1-x^{2}\right)  y^{\prime\prime}-2xy^{\prime}+y=x^3
\qquad-1<x<1
$$
With boundary conditions $y\left(  x\right)  ,y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  $
bounded as $x\rightarrow-1^{+}$ and $x\rightarrow1^{-}$.

### Non computer solution

Let the solution to be
$$
y\left(  x\right)  =y_{h}\left(  x\right)  +y_{p}\left(  x\right)
$$
Where $y_{h}\left(  x\right)  $ is the homogeneous solution to $\left(
1-x^{2}\right)  y^{\prime\prime}-2xy^{\prime}+y=0$ and $y_{p}\left(  x\right)
$ is a particular solution. Now, since $\left(  1-x^{2}\right)  y^{\prime
\prime}-2xy^{\prime}+y=0$ is a Legendre ODE but with a non-integer order,
then its solution is not the normal terminating Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$, but instead is given by
$$
y_{h}\left(  x\right)  =c_{1}\bar{P}_{n}\left(  x\right)  +c_{2}\bar{Q}%
_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$
Where $\bar{P}_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ is called the Legendre function of order
$n$ and $\bar{Q}_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ is called the Legendre function of
the second kind of order $n$, and $y_{p}\left(  x\right)  $ is a particular
solution. The particular solution can be found, using method of undetermined
coefficients to be $y_{p}\left(  x\right)  =-\frac{1}{11}x^{3}-\frac{6}{11}x$.
Hence the general solution becomes
$$
y\left(  x\right)  =c_{1}\bar{P}_{n}\left(  x\right)  +c_{2}\bar{Q}_{n}\left(
x\right)  -\frac{1}{11}x\left(  x^{2}+6\right)
$$
Since the solution must be bounded as $x\rightarrow\pm1$, then we must set
$c_{1}=0$ and $c_{2}=0$, because both $\bar{P}_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ and
 $\bar{Q}_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ are unbounded at the end points
($\bar{Q}_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ blows up at $x=\pm1$ and $\bar{P}_{n}\left(
x\right)  $ blows up at only $x=-1$), therefore the final solution contains
only the particular solution
$$
y\left(  x\right)  =-\frac{1}{11}x\left(  x^{2}+6\right)
$$

### Mathematica solution

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode  = (1-x^2)y''[x]-2 x y'[x]+y[x]==x^3;
sol  = y[x]/.First@DSolve[ode,y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Actually, Mathematica solution above is way too complicated. Mathematica seems to made it too complicated due to the $x^3$ forcing term in the right, the particular solution it came up with is complicated. Compare the above to just the homogeneous solution

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode  = (1-x^2)y''[x]-2 x y'[x]+y[x]==0;
sol  = y[x]/.First@DSolve[ode,y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple gives the much simpler overall solution

```
ode:= (1-x^2)*diff(y(x),x$2)-2*x*diff(y(x),x)+y(x)=x^3;
dsolve(ode,y(x));
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In Mathematica notations, the above is

```
sol=C[1] LegendreP[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[5]),x]+C[2] LegendreQ[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[5]),x]-x^3/11-6 x/11;
```

How can one use `DSolve` and specify the bounded boundary conditions in order to get ride of the homogeneous solution part?

Or does one have to use the above solution, and then try to eliminate `C[1] LegendreP[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[5]),x]+C[2] LegendreQ[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[5]),x]` from it, by other means? May be taking limits and such to force these out of the solution?

There are lots of ODE's, where the boundary condition are of this type (i.e. solution is bounded at one end, or bounded at origin, for example, in the heat PDE inside a disk, the solution must be bounded in the center of the disk). So it will be useful to know how to specify such boundary condition directly.

### Appendix

Plots of the Legendre functions, showing they are not bounded at ends of the domain.

```
 Plot[ LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[ LegendreQ[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[5]),x],{x,-1,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform yes, thanks, that was typo. I added the minus sign.

Comment: Providing `DSolve` with boundary conditions, `DSolve[{ode, y[1] == -7/11, y[-1] == 7/11}, y[x], {x, -1, 1}]`, leads to the error message, `DSolve::bvlim`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey interesting. How long did you have to wait to get the error? on 11.3, I waited for almost 10 minutes, then had to terminate it. It hanged or may be need more time?  I am using windows 7. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OId2j.png)

Comment: I waited 15 minutes or so, not sure.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I see. Thanks. I will try again then and wait longer this time :)